# How to make the original URL inaccessible but keep the RewriteRule working?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a page that is originally

```
https://www.domain.com/page.php
```

and I am redirecting it to

```
https://www.domain.com/page
```

with

```
RewriteRule ^page/?$ page.php [L,NC]
```

Is there a way to maake it accessible ONLY with `page` but when somebody types in `page.php` they are redirected to a 404.html for example?

Answer (score 0):

why not

RewriteRule ^page.php$ error_404.php

?

Answer (score 0):

Yes that can be done using another rule:

```
# block direct request for /page.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /page\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]

RewriteRule ^page/?$ page.php [L,NC]
```